# scope of \renewcommand in a tabular environment

Tags: macros, pandoc

I'm creating a tex file from markdown via pandoc, and to overcome the inherent markup limitations I thought I'd try to redefine the `\emph` and `\textbf` macros in the latex template, to enable finer control over the formatting. For instance, in a specific section of the document I'd like `**text**` to become `{\bfseries\scshape text}`. 
It works well enough, but somehow `\renewcommand` has a very limited scope in a tabular environment: I end up having to add it to every single line. Is this the normal behaviour? Is there a workaround to expand the scope to the whole tabular environment?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\fb}[1]{{\scshape#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\textbf{a}a\\
\renewcommand*{\textbf}[1]{\fb{#1}}\textbf{a}a\\
\textbf{a}a\\
\textbf{a}a
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

*Note:* I'm aware that I could simply use raw tex markup in the markdown source, but I'd like to avoid this alternative strategy in the interest of writer-oriented legibility.

Comment: it is not wise to redefine latex commands/macros. rather define new one. otherwise you will have awful mess i your code. and don't make redefinition in document. let be collected in preamble. otherwise you will have a lot of problems sooner or later.

Comment: yes, I know it runs against all the rules. But markdown syntax has its appeal, and I prefer to have a clean text as input at the cost of an "awful mess" in the template, rather than the opposite. The alternative, keeping the writer happy, would be a convoluted AST filter that replaces `** **` with a user-defined macro `\mytextbf{}` that I would overwrite instead of `\textbf{}`. So far I haven't seen any reason to introduce this additional step (I will if I notice unexpected problems with formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All cells hold their contents local. `\global` defines it globally:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\fb[1]{{\scshape#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\textbf{a}a\\
\global\let\textbf\fb  \textbf{a}a\\
\textbf{a}a\\
\textbf{a}a
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

However, it is not a good idea to overwrite existing LaTeX macros

Comment: Thanks, it does extend the scope, but a little too much as it bleeds outside tabular. I could of course undo this at the end of tabular with `\global\let\textbf\oldtextbf` (saved earlier), but out of curiosity is there a way to restrict the scope?

Answer (score 0):

As Zarko said, it's  best not to mess with standard latex macros if you can, however, I realise that you sometimes have no choice if you want to modify automatically produced output, such as the output from pandoc.

I am not sure if this is an option but the easiest way is to use a custom `tabular` environment that "locally" redefines `\textbf` for that environment. Using this approach, here's your modified MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\fb}[1]{{\scshape#1}}

\newenvironment{Tabular}[1]%
  {\renewcommand*{\textbf}[1]{\fb{##1}}\tabular{#1}}%
  {\endtabular}

\begin{document}
  \begin{Tabular}{l}
    \textbf{a}a\\
    \textbf{a}a\\
    \textbf{a}a
  \end{Tabular}

  \textbf{a}
\end{document}
```

which produces the expected

[image]

To apply this to all tabular environments with minimal effort you could use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\fb}[1]{{\scshape#1}}

\let\realTabular\tabular% save real tabular environment
\let\realEndTabular\endtabular% save end real tabular environment
\renewenvironment{tabular}[1]%
   {\renewcommand*{\textbf}[1]{\fb{##1}}\realTabular{#1}}
   {\realEndTabular}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{l}
    \textbf{a}a\\
    \textbf{a}a\\
    \textbf{a}a
  \end{tabular}

  \textbf{a}
\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

Btw, through instead of `\renewcommand*{\textbf}[1]{\fb{##1}}` you could use `\let\textbf\fb`

Comment: That's an elegant strategy; unfortunately in my case I want to redefine `\textbf` half way through a tabular environment and until its end.